# Invalid Column exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hi guys I am getting this exception when I try to run the vehicles page.

> Invalid column name 'MakeID'.

I have two models:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Make")]
    public int MakeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Make Make { get; set; }
}

public class Make
{
    public int MakeID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The error is being thrown in my vehicles controller here

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vehicles = db.Vehicles.Include(v => v.Make);
    return View(vehicles.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Is this code first? Did you forget to add a migration and update the database?

Comment: So is there a `MakeID` column in your `Vehicle` table?

Comment: Hi Scott Let me start by letting you know I have no idea what I'm doing as I'm totally new to this. Yes I have tried migrating and updating the database numerous times. Is there a way I can totally delete the database and start again?

Comment: Hi James, I deleted the database from the solution but for some reason it seems to still be holding data somewhere. I'm a bit confused by this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj591621.aspx basically you enable-migrations, then add-migration 'name', then update-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add/Enable Migrations. Update the Database. Most of the case improper update causes the issue. There is no problem with your above code.

**Make sure:** you have Updated the Database Tables after adding new columns.

- Run the `Update-Database` command in Package Manager Console.

Make sure your column Foreign Key Relationship / Mappings are ok.

- You have to `check it out manually`.

There are four ways to Drop and Create the Database. Based on several conditions. OR you can manually delete the Database from `SQL Server`.

- Good Article and Source can be [found here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) - Programatically.

**Note:** Recreating the Database will `lose the entire existing data`. There is one way to avoid this problem. [It's providing Seed Data to the database / Tables on create](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx).